# How do I predict when I'm going to run out of memory

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory

We have a swing based application that does complex processing on data.  One of the prerequisites for our software is that any given column cannot have too many unique values.  If the number is numeric, the user would need to discretize the data before they could from our tool.

Unfortunately, the algorithms we are using are combinatorially expensive in memory depending on the number of unique values per column.  Right now with the wrong dataset, the app would run out of memory very quickly.  Before doing one of these operations that would run out of memory, we should be able to calculate roughly how much memory the operation will need.  It would be nice if we could check how much memory the app currently is using, estimate if the app is going to run out of memory, and show an error message accordingly rather than running out of memory.  Using java.lang.Runtime, we can find the free memory, total memory, and max memory, but is this really helpful?  Even if it appears we won't have enough heap space, it could be that if we wait 30 milliseconds the garbage collector will run, and suddenly we have more than enough heap space to run our operation.  Is there anyway to really predict if we are going to run out of memory?

Comment: Don't look at available memory; just look at total memory and know your program's "base line". So if before these calculations you're normally at 50M (say), and total memory is 500M (say), you can expect 450M to be available

Comment: One other issue to consider: free memory / total memory / max memory doesn't take into account the fact that your allocations will need to be contiguous (assuming the jvm and the clr are similar in this regard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar for a database application where the number of rows that were loaded could not be estimated. So in the loop that processes the result set I'm calling a "MemorWatcher" method that would check the memory that was free.

If the available memory goes under a certain threshold the watcher would force a garbage collection and re-check. If there still wasn't enough memory the watcher method signals this to the caller with an exception. The caller can gracefully recover from that exception - as opposed to the OutOfMemoryException which sometimes leaves Swing totally unstable.

Comment: +1 - but a note that you can't really force a garbage collection, you can just hint for it.

Comment: This is what we were thinking also, but my concern is as Lucas said, the garbage collector is not guaranteed to run.

Comment: @Jay: you are right it's not guaranteed to run, but it's still easier to "bail out" in that situation than to handle an OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 0):

I don't have expertise on this, but I feel you can take an extra step of bytecode analysis using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to preempt bugs like null pointer exception, out of memory exception etc.

Comment: yup it is, AFAIK my previous employer (one of the biggest java shops out there) used bytecode analysis on their production machines. But, that is it what I know about it. Unfortunately, didn't work with that team.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you run your application with the maximum amount of memory you need from the outset (using `-Xms`) I don't think you can achieve anything useful, since other applications will be able to consume memory before your app needs it.

Have you considered using Soft/WeakReferences, and letting garbage collection reap objects that you could possible recalculate/regenerate on the fly ?